# Hi I am getting error \missing end csname inserted. I have attached the error with image

Tags: missing

[image][image]

Hi i am getting error while running latex file. It is showing
\missing endcsname inserted.   \relax

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To get a mutcg better error message **do not use** `pdftexify`, use instead `pdflatex`, `bibtex` or `biber`, twice `pdflatex`. Then check the resulting `*.log` file for the **first** error message, copy and paste it to your question ...

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response- Ram

Comment: I have used pdf latex, but still i am getting same error that missing endcsname inserted

Comment: Well, without seeing any code we can not help more :-(( Please add the first line of your log file to your question (it shows tex distribution and excact version number; perhaps your system is outdated?), add the first error you get to your question and best would be you can add an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) resulting in your error message ...

Comment: Ensure to make a thorough update to your MiKTeX.

Comment: Well, the current version of MiKTeX is `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)`, you are using the totaly outdated version `-1.40.11`. In this case delete the old installation and install MiKTeX completly new (use netinstaller to get a complete MiKTeX, omit basic MiKTeX).